# Alert confirmation Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have put in place a JS prompt just before deleting a user from the DB. But for some reason for the life of me I cannot spot why it is failing - I am pulling in the small bit of script from my JS folder:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?'));
};
for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
}
```

And using it here inside of my user.php file which lists out the users:

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, emailAddress FROM customers ORDER BY firstname ASC;";
    $result = $dbc->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        while($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                "<div class='trow'>" .  
                "<span class='fullName'>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . 
                $row["lastname"]. " </span>" . 
                "<span class='email'>" . $row["emailAddress"]. " </span>" . 
                "<span><a class='deleteMember confirmation' id='deletePrompt' href='deleteMember.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Delete user'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a></span>" . 
                "<span class='editMember'><a href='#' title='Edit user'><i class='fa fa-cogs'></i></a></span>" . 
                "<br></div>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Btw I am aware that isn't the nicest way to do things but I am learning, I am using the class name 'confirmation' to enable the prompt. but it still deletes the record when I hit it it but no longer a prompt.

Comment: It's because you are putting a confirmation on an A-tag..

Comment: It should still work?

Comment: Shouldn't your confirmIt function return something?  (or is the 'if' thing a fancy syntax I'm not used to?)  var corfirmIt = function(e) { return confirm("are you sure..."); };

Comment: I think you also need to catch the event and `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: You're not really doing anything with the return value of that `confirm` call. You should check that value (like you're doing ATM), but based on the user clicking OK or Cancel, you should handle the event (`e.preventDefault` + `e.stopPropagation` or follow the link, or do an AJAX call)

Comment: try adding the return confirm in the onclick of that a element (see my edited answer below).  That should prevent the page redirect.  If not, the last option would be to pass the id into a js function and do the redirect if confirm == true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to return false from the function if you want to stop the action.

```
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');
};
```

And on you PHP

`"<span><a class='deleteMember confirmation' onClick="return confirmIt()" href='deleteMember.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Delete user'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a></span>"`

This **SHOULD** do the trick.

Comment: Then you will have to call confirmIt inside onClick attribute of the href element.

Comment: and that is all I need to do? Trim off all my other code?

Comment: You will need to change the single line in PHP code and as for JS, confirmIt variable should suffice.

Comment: But by doing it this, like the example below, when you hit cancel, it still deleted the record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76366/discussion-between-arun-poudel-and-user3725879).

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit extra for what is needed.  Why not 'return confirm':

```
function confirmIt(){    
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');
}
```

then call "confirmIt" on click.  (Really you could put the 'return confirm' in your onclick for the A element:

```
<span><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');" class='deleteMember confirmation' id='deletePrompt' href='deleteMember.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Delete user'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a></span>
```

last option would be to pass the id to a js function:

```
function confirmIt(e){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?'))
      {
          window.location.href = "deleteMember.php?id=" + e;
      }
}

<span><a onclick='confirmIt(".$row['id'].")' class='deleteMember confirmation' id='deletePrompt' href='' title='Delete user'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are not grabbing the results of the confirm() before doing your compare.  Take a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Try getting the results of the confirm first then put that in your if statement.

Also, on a fail you want to return false to keep the anchor behavior from continuing or it will process the delete action for both choices.

Comment: So by using this method, it still deletes the record even if you hit cancel.

Comment: right, you have to return 'false' to cancel the behavior of the anchor tag. The return confirm(); methods above are very clean, I would recommend using one of those.